# how to make a new line before a digit in a string

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to cut the string before the digits so it will form a new string. i will make sure there are no other digits (e.g. for measurements) except for steps.

example:

```
a = 'HOW TO COOK RICE - Chapter 1: 1 rinse water once 2 add one and a half cup of water for every cup of rice 3 cover the pot and simmer'
```

Result should be a new line before every digits except the chapter digit

```
HOW TO COOK RICE - Chapter 1
1 rinse water once
2 add one and a half cup of water for every cup of rice
3 cover the pot and simmer
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: You also need to ensure that your question is clear. In this case, should the prefix "HOW TO COOK RICE - Chapter 1: " simply be ignored in the returned string? How exactly is the code to detect the end of the chapter heading--will it always be "Chapter " followed by digits followed by ": "?

Comment: What happens if the instruction itself contains a number? Say for example `2 add 1 1/2 cups of water for every cup of rice`

Comment: this is just an example. i will make sure there is no other number except the steps in the string

Comment: yes, "HOW TO COOK RICE - Chapter 1 should be ignored. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex

```
a = 'HOW TO COOK RICE - Chapter 1: 1 rinse water once 2 add one and a half cup of water for every cup of rice 3 cover the pot and simmer'
idx=[i.start() for i in re.finditer('(\d{1,} \w{1,})', a)]
if idx:
    print(a[:idx[0]])
else:
    print(a)
for i,index in enumerate(idx):
    if not i==len(idx)-1:
        print(a[index:idx[i+1]])
    else:
        print(a[idx[i]:])
```

Output

```
HOW TO COOK RICE - Chapter 1: 
1 rinse water once 
2 add one and a half cup of water for every cup of rice 
3 cover the pot and simmer
```

Comment: thanks! this is what i am looking for. however, it does not print the last digit (3 cover the pot and simmer). sorry, i forgot to put it on expected result.

Comment: @sunnyvalecalifornia no worries edited the code. Make sure you do not have any number inside the instructions

Comment: cool. thanks! one more thing, how can i print the "HOW TO COOK RICE - Chapter 1"?

Comment: @sunnyvalecalifornia done

Comment: thanks! i accepted the solution. :)

Comment: after step 9, the next digit becomes 0 and i can see the "1" as the last character in step 9. e.g.

Comment: 9 serve 1 and then a new line 0

Comment: @sunnyvalecalifornia Edited again